# Configuring activemq messages

Tags: queue, activemq-classic

In my project I am using acticemq.Now I need to configure my messages to be automatically deleted from the queue after certain time limit(say 24hrs).Can anybody say how and where to configure that.Can any one give me sample code to do so...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JMS Time To Live](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-set-the-message-expiration.html) on the message to tell the broker how long the Message should remain on the Queue.  You can [configure](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html) what happens when a message is expired on the broker as well, it can be sent to a DLQ for instance.